# rendered page on axios request logs on console but does not display on user's page

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, axios

I have this application in development that when the user hits submit, an Axios request is sent to the express endpoint that performs logic and redirects the user to another "confirmation" endpoint that's to handle rendering an ejs page.

However, the page is not rendered but rather logged on the console. I tried rendering the page on the initial axios entry endpoint but it still logs on the console.

any suggestion, tips, advice or fix would be appreciated

Here is my code snippet. I removed the logic to not bulk up the code

//client entry point

```
      axios.post(`/verify/${reference}`, { appData, programData })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e.response.data)
            })
```

// node entry point

```
app.post('/verify/:ref', (req, res) => { 
    res.redirect('confirmation')
})
```

// exit, where a page is to be rendered without user action

```
app.get('/confirmation', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.render('confirmation', { programData })
})
```

so at the end of the cycle, the browser logs the HTML on the same entry page without redirecting the user?

tried as detailed above, was expecting a redirect to the '/confirmation' endpoint with a new page rendered to the user without user action.

// Result
browser logs HTML on the console based on the Axios post request

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you want to redirect what the **user** sees based on the Axios request you need to actually do something in the Axios handlers besides logging. Axios follows the redirect and receives the rendered content of `/confirmation`, which is precisely what you told it to do.